Magento UI component form not saving
I have a Magento 2 UI component form. Form loads without any errors but when I try to save it then it redirected back to same page with a parameter added as undefined. I had added var_dump die statement in the Save controller it seems it never enters the save controller. The url change from https://testing.k-sale.com/admin/managefaq/faq/new/ to https://testing.k-sale.com/admin/managefaq/faq/new/undefined
faq_form.xml
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_form.faq_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faq_form.faq_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FAQ</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">faq_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="back">
                <label>Back</label>
                <url path="*/*/index"/>
            </button>
            <button name="save" class="Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Save"/>
        </buttons>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>faq_form.faq_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="faq_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="managefaq/faq/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Avesh\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Faq\Form\DataProvider" name="faq_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>faq_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general_information">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Avesh\Faq\Model\Source\Faq\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="question">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="answer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">answer</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Save

/**
 *
 * @category  Custom Development
 * @email     contactus@learningmagento.com
 * @author    Avesh Naik
 * @website   learningmagento.com
 * @Date      31-07-2024
 */

namespace Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Save implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * Retrieve button-specified settings
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
        ];
    }
}

Avesh\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Faq\Form\DataProvider
<?php

/**
 *
 * @category  Custom Development
 * @email     contactus@learningmagento.com
 * @author    Avesh Naik
 * @website   learningmagento.com
 * @Date      30-07-2024
 */

namespace Avesh\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Faq\Form;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Avesh\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\Collection;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 * @package Avesh\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Faq\Form
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_loadedData;

    /**
     * @var \Avesh\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * Dataprovider Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param \Avesh\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\Collection $faqCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Collection $faqCollection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName);
        $this->collection = $faqCollection;
    }
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $faq) {
            $this->_loadedData[$faq->getId()] = $faq->getData();
        }
        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}

Save Controller
<?php

/**
 *
 * @category  Custom Development
 * @email     contactus@learningmagento.com
 * @author    Avesh Naik
 * @website   learningmagento.com
 * @Date      30-07-2024
 */

namespace Avesh\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

/**
 * Class Save
 * @package Avesh\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq
 */
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_faqRepository;

    protected $_faqFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Avesh\Faq\Api\FaqRepositoryInterface $faqRepository,
        \Avesh\Faq\Api\Data\FaqInterfaceFactory $faqFactory,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_faqRepository = $faqRepository;
        $this->_faqFactory = $faqFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump("herere"); die;
        try {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $faq = $this->_faqFactory->create();
            if(isset($data["id"]) && $data["id"]){
                $faq = $this->_faqRepository->getById($data["id"]);
            }
            $faq->setAnswer($params["answer"])
                ->setQuestion($params["question"])
                ->setStatus($params["status"]);
            $this->_faqRepository->save($faq);
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__("Something went wrong while saving it"));
        }
        $redirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $redirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}


Save controller or Saves ?

Let me update the post. The thing is its not passing there at all

Try to Update the code as below :

faq_form.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_form.faq_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">faq_form</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faq_form.faq_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FAQ</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="faq_save" xsi:type="string">Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="faq_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Avesh\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Faq\Form\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">faq_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="managefaq/faq/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general_information">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Avesh\Faq\Model\Source\Faq\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form_data_source</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="question">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form_data_source</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="answer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">answer</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form_data_source</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>


Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Save.php

<?php

namespace Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\GenericButton;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Save extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve button-specified settings
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl())
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('managefaq/faq/save');
    }
}


Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button\Back.php

<?php

namespace Avesh\Faq\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Back extends Container implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve button-specified settings
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/index');
    }
}

After Updating the files, Please run the compile and static-content deploy command.

Same problem. I am running magento 2.4.7 on a docker env.

@AveshNaik
If possible can you send me the module via dropBox or google drive, So that I can check

I have updated in the file faq_form.xml, Please check @Avesh

In faq_form.xml
In submit <submitUrl path="managefaq/faq/saves"/>
you are passing saves which should be save
please update and try with this
<submitUrl path="managefaq/faq/save"/>


I checked the code and changed the name to save. Still same
